# Moving files from one directory to another

Tags: python-3.x

The problem i am having is that it seems that my program will not move a file from one directory to another

)

thanks for the help

```
for folderName, subFolders,fileName in os.walk("C:\\Users\\camhu\\Downloads"):
    for subFolder in subFolders:
        if "Python" in subFolder:
            print(os.path.join(folderName,subFolder))
            shutil.copytree(os.path.join(folderName,subFolder),"C:\\Users\\camhu\\Documents")
```

Comment: why not just use `shutil.move`?

Comment: @Onyambu would shutil.move work with directory’s from what I was aware it only worked on files to move

Comment: Bit you are moving files.

Comment: @Onyambu that worked